# MVC 2 post-render extensibility point (custom action filters, even?)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2, action-filter

I've got an .net MVC2 project, and I can't find a method to override which will allow me to perform some logic following a page render...

I'm currently using the OnActionExecuted / OnActionExecuting (and the OnResultExecuting / OnResultExecuted in my controllers to do a variety of things, the important one here being to place some objects onto thread local storage(TLS) - current user, for example.

As such, I do the 'setup' of the TLS in the OnActionExecuting, but I can't do the 'teardown' until *after* the page has been rendered.

Any suggestions? I don't want to leave parts of the TLS setup.

specifically, my view is calling a property of an object which needs to access TLS before I tear it down.

Thanks,
Dave

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up overriding the 'OnResultExecuted' method.

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet for the location of the tear down is the Application_EndRequest event inside the global.asax.